# Avoid unnecessary constructor calls while inserting element to std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Say I have `std::unordered_map < int, std::vector< int >  > my_hashtable`  and I insert a new entry:

```
my_hashtable.insert(make_pair(a_key, std::vector()));
```

This works but it invokes constructors and assignment ops multiple times.  (1) std::vector(), (2) make_pair arguments are pass by value, copy (3) make_pair return type by value, copy again (4) function insert will make copy again.

Please correct me if I count it incorrectly.

Hence, we are making too many copies, we really only should call constructor once, how can we achieve that (under C++11)?

I noticed that std::unordered_map::insert has a version working with move constructor, but not sure how to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the examples of [std::unordered_map::emplace()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace):

```
my_hashtable.emplace(
   std::piecewise_construct,
   std::forward_as_tuple(a_key),
   std::forward_as_tuple()
);
```

Here, there is no unnecessary constructor call.

Comment: This is precisely what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the signature of the value_type of the map: It is `std::pair<map::key_type, map::mapped_type>` where the key type is const qualified.

This will eliminate a copy/move:

```
typedef std::unordered_map < int, std::vector< int > > hash_table:
my_hashtable.insert(hash_table::value_type(a_key, std::vector()));
```

The signature of the result of make_pair in your example is likely `std::pair<int, vector<...> >` and not `std::pair<const int, vector<...> >`